# Parameter a class with type A or B

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I am trying to parameter a class with a type that is whether A or B and nothing else.

Something like

```
final class ChildClass<A | B> extends MotherClass {
```

This way I can create a `ChildClass<A>` or a `ChildClass<B>` but nothing else.

Is it possible in Java?

---

Edit:

I must specify that I am using Java 8 and that I have no control of classes A and B (which are classes of the Android framework I am working with).

Comment: Nope. Sorry I can't offer an explanation (maybe someone else can). But it's not possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately is not. Search for term `union types in java` or `java either type`.

The most known case of union types in Java is catching multiple exceptions, which is built-in into language, however it would be awful to abuse exceptions for your own types.

[Here](https://blog.jooq.org/2016/02/16/an-ingenious-workaround-to-emulate-sum-types-in-java/) is also interesting workaround.

Comment: Too bad, I guess that is one more elegant implementation that will never come to life...

Comment: you can [cheat, slightly](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64160422/1059372)

Answer (score 2):

With the addition of [this JEP](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/360), there is a rather interesting way to do it now.

You can create an interface that is `sealed`:

```
sealed interface F permits A, B {

    default String name() {
        return "F";
    }
}
```

add the generic type that is going to be *bounded* by this interface:

```
static class WithGenerics<T extends F> {

    private final T t;

    public WithGenerics(T t) {
        this.t = t;
    }

    public void findName() {
        System.out.println(t.name());
    }

}
```

And finally create the two classes `A` and `B`:

```
static final class A implements F {
    .....
}

static final class B implements F {
   .....
}
```

And you have effectively said that only `A` and `B` can be passed to :

```
 WithGenerics<A> a = new WithGenerics<>(new A());
 a.findName();

 WithGenerics<B> b = new WithGenerics<>(new B());
 b.findName();
```

because there can be no type `C` that can potentially implement `F`.

Comment: Very interesting... I think this is all to prepare the ground for real pattern matching

Comment: This answer is helpful and well-explained, thanks. Sadly, I have no control over classes A and B (they're actually part of the Android framework I am working with). Moreover, I am restricted to using Java 8, I forgot to mention it and will edit my post, sorry.

Comment: @EnzoMolion theres nothing to be sorry for, this feature is in preview mode anyway, it's not prod ready yet.

Answer (score 1):

You might be able to check the class type of T like this:

```
public Class Foo<T> extends MotherClass {
    private final Class<T> classType;

    public Foo(Class<T> classType) {
        this.classType = classType;
    }

    public Class<T> getClassType() {
        return this.classType;
    }

    public void method() {
        if (classType.equals(A.class)) {
        //Do something
        } else if (classType.equals(B.class)) {
        //Do something
        }
    }
}
```

Heres an example of creating an object of Foo..

```
Foo<A> foo = new Foo<>(A.class);
```

Hope this helps you if it doesn't leave a comment and I'll try to edit and provide a more helpful answer.

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken but this allows no control over what classe "parametrizes" `Foo`. Nothing, in suggested implementation, forbids to create a `Foo<C>` and that is what I actually try to do. I could have a runtime checking mechanism but that is not really what I am seeking for.

Answer (score 1):

> This way I can create a ChildClass<A> or a ChildClass<B> but nothing else.
> Is it possible in Java?

I am assuming that `A` and `B` are real types and not just generic parameters.  Otherwise, `A` and `B` could be anything so you may as well just have `A`.

So why not just predefine the class to return an instance of whichever ones are allowed?

```
class MyClass<A> extends MotherClass {
    private MyClass() {
    }
    
    public static MyClass<Integer> instanceOfInteger() {
        return new MyClass<Integer>();  
    }
    public static MyClass<String> instanceOfString() {
         return new MyClass<String>();
    }
    // rest of class here
}


MyClass<Integer> mc1 = MyClass.instanceOfInteger();
MyClass<String> mcs = MyClass.instanceOfString();
```

Comment: Correct me if I am mistaken but this allows no control over what classe "parametrizes" `MyClass`. Nothing, in suggested implementation, forbids to create a `MyClass<C>` and that is what I actually try to do. I could have a runtime checking mechanism but that is not really what I am seeking for.

Comment: I guess I misunderstood since you said *This way I can create a ChildClass<A> or a ChildClass<B> but nothing else.* which to me would preclude a ChildClass<C>